# Finding a new polynomial with roots $k$ greater than a given polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

A similar question appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259949/find-the-equation-whose-roots-are-each-six-more-than-the-roots-of-x2-8x-1/1259956), though I wish to ask for polynomials of higher degree.

Let's say we have the polynomial $f(x)=x^4-3x^3-3x^2+4x-6$, and we wish to find a polynomial with roots 3 greater than those of $f(x)$.  I can see that putting $g(x)=f(x-3)$ works, but then we have the expression $$(x-3)^4-3(x-3)^3-3(x-3)^2-4(x-3)+6$$ which will take quite a while to evaluate. (It comes out to $\boldsymbol{x^4-15x^3+78x^2-175x+441}$).

Is there a shortcut to find the polynomial above through some 'trick' (e.g. some form of synthetic division?)

Furthermore, if we wish to find a polynomial with roots $k$ greater than a given polynomial, will this new polynomial have a given 'form' of $k$? E.g. what if I wanted to solve the above question, but with my roots being $4,5,$ or $6$ greater than those of the given polynomial?

Comment: `Is there a shortcut` Not really. What you have *is* the shortcut.

Comment: You say "which will take quite a while to evaluate"? That isn't a very precise criterion. If you are interested in the computational complexity, then computing the coefficients of $f(x - 3)$ using Horner's rule is quite efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your roots will be shifted $3$ units to the right. From there, you can calculate the new roots, using the sum and product of roots formulae to calculate the coefficients of each term. This can be considered a shortcut of sorts. 
For a polynomial $f(x)$ where $$f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$$
$$\alpha\beta\gamma...=(-1)^n\frac{a_0}{a_n}$$
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma+...=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$$
The greek letters represent the roots.

There are other formulae for finding $a_{n-2}$ and so forth. I will give $a_{n-2}$ in cyclic sum notation, but the rest are easily accessible and directly quotable.
$$\sum \alpha\beta=\frac{a_{n-2}}{a_n}$$

Comment: apologies, but what do the greek letters on the LHS of the 2nd line denote?

Comment: Well, his method is more efficient since he doesn't have to calculate the (complex) roots.

Comment: @Mathematrix see the edit above please

Comment: How does your method work for the given example without first finding  all the roots?

Comment: @RobArthan I guess what the answer is getting at is using Vieta's relations for the symmetric polynomials, which does not require actually finding the original roots e.g. $\;\sum (\alpha+3)$ $=\sum \alpha + 4 \cdot 3$ $= 3+12=15\,$, then $\;\sum (\alpha+3)(\beta+3)$ $= \sum \alpha \beta + 6 \cdot \sum \alpha + 6 \cdot 9 = \ldots\;$ It is a legitimate approach, though not necessarily much of a shortcut vs. the direct expansion.

Comment: @dxiv I was just about to type something similar, thanks! But yes, I guess this is more of an alternative which would be somewhat of a shortcut in some cases and vice versa in others, depending on whether the numbers are easy to work with

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think it's really down to the OP to explain what criteria are relevant in his/her application.